# restrict unauthorized login in openshift

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift-origin

I have a scenario to work on where I need to restrict the login giving random username and password which gets created if they don't exist. I want to create logins from my console only, I have tried out using htpassword by referring the official doc but I couldn't get the result.

Comment: Do you want to restrict access to pods only?